# How can I make menu hidden on menu item click?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, navigation

I'm not too familiar with jQuery so I'm having trouble achieving a fairly simple effect that I want.

[Live Test Site](http://screenpartner.norisp.no/~flex/)

So, I have created a resonsive menu for my site. If you resize the window you'll be able to see the mobile version. This works great, except for one thing:

I have anchor links in my menu, which means that the site won't load a new page on click, but instead scroll down to the anchor. My problem with this, is that I don't know how to make the menu close itself when clicking one of these menu items.

Currently, this is the script that allows me the current menu functionality (fa-bars is the hamburger icon, .primary-mobile-nav is the mobile wordpress navigation menu:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var pull        = $('.fa-bars');  
            menu        = $('.primary-mobile-nav');  
            menuHeight  = menu.height();  

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();  
            menu.slideToggle();  
        });
})
jQuery(window).resize(function(){  
    var w = $(window).width();  
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
        menu.removeAttr('style');  
    }  
});
```

I guess to sum it up, my question is: How can I add to the script so that when I click on any of the menu-items the menu gets hidden again?

**EDIT**

So I actually managed to fix this by adding another variable that I called "pullback" and assigned it to the "menu-item a", then I just called the function like this:

```
$(pullback).on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    menu.slideToggle();  
});
```

I'll check out the other answers I got here to see if those solution are better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery snippet out.

```
$("#menu-mobile-navigation a").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    menu.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'm changing my code to this one. Seems cleaner than the one I ghettoed myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
//When we click on a menu item
$('#menu-mobile-navigation li').click(function(){
   //Hide the menu 
   $('.primary-mobile-nav').hide();

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this actually did what I asked, but it did so without the pull animation. I did however find a solution which I'll edit my question with.

Comment: @michaelw90 You could replace .hide() with .slideUp()